# TypeScript: Change of a function argument type is not picked up in forEach within the function

Tags: typescript, foreach

I am working on something that has checkboxes and I don't understand why the following is not valid TypeScript:

```
declare function checkChecked(isAllChecked: boolean): void

declare function determineIfChecked(): boolean

const checkBoxes: number[] = []

const toggleCheckAll = (isAllChecked?: boolean): void => {
  if (isAllChecked === undefined) isAllChecked = determineIfChecked()

  checkBoxes.forEach(() => checkChecked(isAllChecked))
  checkChecked(isAllChecked)
}
```

[Here it is in a TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzAAtwBrAYWLBJGAAosBnAQQggtJoC54AjHHCCCioAlNwBuOLMABQM0JFgIU6bHnigMIGAFssqEAElE7KjVpje-QcLlg8DDAUokAQjgAeIBt1TIdPNoA2gC68AC88KF2Dk4YOADmCYKmJCwQEfD0zKypNAD83HwCQqISUsARAHzwAN4y8PBYiFmM6XmV4V3waKCI+jQiTTlsLjSZmtp6BsYdFnKNRKTuXgwAdIg4MACiUES0FtXOpHNtuWPAIiINx1SnIx3XAL4yQA)

The `isAllChecked` in the call of `checkChecked`  in the `forEach` loop raises an:

> Argument of type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

I'm guessing my understanding of the scope of function arguments is not quite right as I would have thought the if statement should have updated the type of `isAllChecked` to be `boolean` and that this would be carried through to the `forEach` loop.

I can work round this but I would like to understand why this is not valid TypeScript.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/N5LQVw) serve that purpose?  If so I can [edit] the code in your question to that version if you want.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did have a TS playground example to add into the question but I forgot to add the link (which I have now added)

Comment: Just don't use forEach. There's no reason to use that anymore. A `for (... of ...)` would work correctly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known design limitation in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for a full description.

The problem is that the [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) that happens when you check and reassign `isAllChecked` does not persist across function scope boundaries.  So while the compiler knows that `isAllChecked` is definitely `boolean` in the outer scope, that information is completely gone in the scope of the callback `() => checkChecked(isAllChecked)`.  Any narrowing of closed-over values is reset inside a closure.

This happens because *in general* it would be completely unfeasible for the compiler to attempt to keep track of control flow into and out of functions.  The compiler doesn't know when or if the callback `() => checkChecked(isAllChecked)` will be run, because even though *we* know that [the array `forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) runs essentially synchronously, that information is not part of the type system.  In general, a callback passed to some function could be called at any time.

And in general, closed-over values *could* be reassigned or modified before that time. In your particular case, you never modify `isAllChecked` after the callback is created.  But the compiler would need to spend extra resources to check that this is true, and therefore all closures would require the compiler to check for reassignments of all closed-over values everywhere, which would add a lot of compilation time for a benefit that only happens on occasion.

So that's what's going on.  The compiler can't keep track of what happens to closed-over values inside of callbacks, and it doesn't really try.

---

I know you're not asking for a workaround, but for completeness, the usual workaround in cases like this is to copy the value to a `const` once you know it will never change:

```
const toggleCheckAll = (isAllChecked?: boolean): void => {
    if (isAllChecked === undefined) isAllChecked = false;
    const i = isAllChecked; // boolean
    checkBoxes.forEach(() => checkChecked(i)) // okay
    checkChecked(isAllChecked)
}
```

The `i` constant has type `boolean` and not `boolean | undefined` because of the control flow narrowing of `isAllChecked` to `boolean` at the time of the assignment to `i`.  Which means that `checkChecked(i)` is always acceptable no matter where it appears; there is no control flow narrowing of `i` to be reset.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF0QC3AawGFcw8RgAueACgEs0BBCCI-MygIySQhChQEp4AXgB88AG5IawANwBYAFChIsBMnRYwxPACEkADxBpKfAJ4BtALqL1meBiQBzRzxYlGEYdToe3pYAD8HFw8fPyUktLCYgDeivAJ8DQAZt4MTH5kwkJC8ACuKKDJNChkgj4Z2lm5yVAQaCDyComIqHY0XhXMVbLwAPR98JzcvCjxiVr4eoZoAHTJSDAAolBaVFSCojj4mcC0-IID8Eh4UKbjCZMku7Tp3azA-IoAvopAA)

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very clear and I now understand why an error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point for a parameter to be optional if its type is `boolean` and it  is the only parameter in the function. Just use `toggleCheckAll(true)` instead of `toggleCheckAll()`. Plus, if you are declaring a function, use `declare function` instead of `declare const`

```js
declare function checkChecked(isAllChecked: boolean): void

const toggleCheckAll = (isAllChecked: boolean): void => { 
  checkBoxes.forEach(() => checkChecked(isAllChecked))
  checkChecked(isAllChecked)
}
```

Comment: I've updated my example now to make it a bit clearer why the type of the `isAllChecked` is `boolean?`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `isAllChecked?: boolean` allows for `undefined`, while `isAllChecked: boolean` doesn't.

Either use a default value for the function, or add a check for undefined inside the function:

```
const toggleCheckAll = (isAllChecked: boolean = false): void => {
  checkBoxes.forEach(() => checkChecked(isAllChecked))
  checkChecked(isAllChecked)
}
```

Or

```
const toggleCheckAll = (isAllChecked?: boolean): void => {
  if (isAllChecked == null) {
    isAllChecked = false;
  }

  checkBoxes.forEach(() => checkChecked(isAllChecked))
  checkChecked(isAllChecked)
}
```

#### EDIT

The second option doesn't work. See this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73571834/2089675). Rather than introducing a new variable, I would suggest the [Null Coalascing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator (`??`):

```
const toggleCheckAll = (isAllChecked?: boolean): void => {
  if (isAllChecked == null) {
    isAllChecked = false;
  }

  checkBoxes.forEach(() => checkChecked(isAllChecked ?? false))
  checkChecked(isAllChecked)
}
```